# Creating SEO and human freindly/readable URLs using PHP and IIS7

Tags: php, iis, iis-7

I am running PHP5.3.6 and IIS7. I am currently working on a product centric site where I have one php page that dynamically generates a page based on a query string such as `/product.php?id=12345`.

The volume of products that I have in the database varies, but measures in the hundreds. They have unique IDs and names.

I want for each page to be addresses by their name instead of by the query string.

For example, instead of:

```
/product.php?id=12345
```

I would prefer:

```
/acme-super-widget-in-blue-with-cool-groovy-gadget-attachment
```

I have the `URL Rewrite` component in IIS7, but I don't want to enter values manually. I would rather have a dynamic process in place. I believe the needed functionailty here is to add an URL Rewrite rule to the `web.config` file, but I'm not sure if that is true or the best approach.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using the ID along with the name so that you can support products with the same name (future proofing), or products with non-ascii characters... should you have international names. I would also recommend using only ascii characters in the URL's for now as I've noticed some sites and browser tend to expand non-ascii characters in to ugly percent encoding.

IIS 7 is a bit trickier than Apache, but I think this might work for you http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2008/05/31/urlrewrite-module-for-iis7.aspx

Here is an example rewrite rule which will strip the name off the id and pass just the id to the script.

**IIS 7 Using the module in the link above**

Match URL

```
^([0-9]+)[^/]*/?$
```

Action

```
index.php?id={R:1} [QSA,L]
```

**Apache just for good messure ;)**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)[^/]*/?$ index.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Here is a PHP function that will generate the id name portion of your friendly URLs.

```
function friendlyURL($id, $title) {

    $string = $title;
    $paramcount = func_num_args();
    for ($i = 2; $i < $paramcount; $i++) {
        $string .= "-" . func_get_arg($i);
    }
    $string = preg_replace('`&(amp;)?#?[a-z0-9]+;`i', '-', $string);
    $string = htmlentities($string, ENT_COMPAT, "utf-8");
    $string = preg_replace("`&([a-z]+);`i", "", $string);
    $string = preg_replace("`['\[\]]`", "", $string);

    $tmp = $string;
    $string = preg_replace(array("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/", "`[-]+`"), "-", $string);

    $string = trim($string, '-');
    return trim($id . "-" . $string, '-');
}
```

This would give you URL's like

Product ID = 12345, Name = "acme super widget"

```
/12345-acme-super-widget/
```

Product ID = 12345, Name = "Japanese product ギター"

```
/12345-japanese-product/
```

Comment: This code is fantastic; thank you. Becasue of the dynamic nature of the site, I can't add entries manually via the IIS7 control panel. What would be the best way to use PHP to add the appropriate rewrite rules to the web.config file? Thanks again.

Comment: I've never tested this option but it reportedly handles all Apache style mod re-write options and use of a .htaccess file per directory.  http://www.micronovae.com/ModRewrite/ModRewrite.html

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this: http://www.iis.net/download/URLRewrite is exactly what you need.